# Azure Function add out bindings based on input bindings

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I was wondering if it's possible to add out bindings based on the input bindings.
For example,

I will store endpoint/access keys for various endpoints and generate out bindings based on those upon execution, instead of adding them manually everything to the azure function.

if my Cosmos SQL contains,

a. EndPoint A
b. EndPoint B
c. EndPoint C

my Azure function will take input data from this table and 
create three out bindings. then send the triggered data to those endpoints.

is it possible?

Comment: don't know what language you are using, but i have one for c# https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8p8RmOg9iw and one for javascript  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYQseNLX9Pw

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are in .NET Functions, this is possible with [imperative bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#binding-at-runtime).

Simple example with queue to blob:

```cs
public static void Run(string myQueueItem, IBinder binder)
{
    using (var writer = binder.Bind<TextWriter>(new BlobAttribute(
                $"samples-output/{myQueueItem}", FileAccess.Write)))
    {
        writer.Write("Hello World!");
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks! Is this possible in .csx(within portal)? or also possible only cs (in visual studio)?

Comment: Yes, both, just accept `Binder` / `IBinder` as input parameter and reference proper namespaces (this part is easier in VS)